# mergeTwoLists: How the memory works in Python?

Tags: python, merge, singly-linked-list

I am working on the merge-two-list problem from the leetcode. This problem requires to merge two linked lists in a sorted way. The solution code is given below. In the code, variable prev keeps being updated and eventually has the only one node from l1 or l2. However, prehead seems to memorize whenever prev.next is executed. However, it does not memorize when prev=prev.next is executed.

For example, if you run this code for `l1 = 1->3->4, l2 = 1->2->4`. At the end:

```
prev = ListNode{val: 4, next: ListNode{val: 4, next: None}}. 

prehead = ListNode{val: -1, next: ListNode{val: 1, next: ListNode{val: 1, next: ListNode{val: 2, next: ListNode{val: 3, next: ListNode{val: 4, next: ListNode{val: 4, next: None}}}}}}}
```

```py
        prehead = ListNode(-1)

        prev = prehead
        while l1 and l2:

            if l1.val <= l2.val:
                prev.next = l1
                l1 = l1.next
            else:
                prev.next = l2
                l2 = l2.next 


            prev = prev.next

        # exactly one of l1 and l2 can be non-null at this point, so connect
        # the non-null list to the end of the merged list.
        prev.next = l1 if l1 is not None else l2

        return prehead.next
```

Comment: Because of the idnentation I am assuming that it is the same Class coming from [here](https://stackabuse.com/python-linked-lists/)?

Comment: What's your question? I suggest you write the objects down on a piece of paper, and draw pointers from variables and object attributes to the objects as it does the assignments.

Comment: My question is the following: we have two linked lists that are copy of each other (prev and prehead). I understand, prehead is updated when we do prev.next = l1 for the first time. Then, we re-declared prev as prev = prev.next. So far so good, but then, we we do prev.next again, prehead gets updated as if there was no re-declaration of prev. I mean how do the changes in prev affect prehead after the re-declaration?